# Dependency not satisfiable error with libdbus

Tags: 14.04, dependencies

On trying to install a `.deb` package I get this error

```
Dependency is not satisfiable: libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14)
```

Tried these commands without success:

```
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install -f
apt get -a --configure
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here

Comment: Don't do random apt incantations. You can do a lot of damage.

Comment: I just tried w/e ppl suggesting in order threads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem** is that Ubuntu 14.04 uses libdbus-1-3 version 1.6.18. That's why you cannot install a package that requires 1.9.14 or higher.

**One simple solution** is to upgrade to a newer release of Ubuntu. For example, Ubuntu 16.04 uses libdbus-1-3 version 1.10.6.

**Another simple solution** is to use an older version of the software you want to install. The requirement for libdbus-1-3 version 1.9.14 indicates that it's not from a currently-supported Ubuntu repository anyway.

Here's one easy way to figure it out the different versions provided by each release (and repository) of Ubuntu:

```
$ rmadison libdbus-1-3
 libdbus-1-3 | 1.4.18-1ubuntu1    | precise          | amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 libdbus-1-3 | 1.4.18-1ubuntu1.8  | precise-security | amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 libdbus-1-3 | 1.4.18-1ubuntu1.8  | precise-updates  | amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 libdbus-1-3 | 1.6.18-0ubuntu4    | trusty           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 libdbus-1-3 | 1.6.18-0ubuntu4.4  | trusty-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 libdbus-1-3 | 1.6.18-0ubuntu4.5  | trusty-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 libdbus-1-3 | 1.8.12-1ubuntu5    | vivid            | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 libdbus-1-3 | 1.10.6-1ubuntu3    | xenial           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 libdbus-1-3 | 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.1  | xenial-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 libdbus-1-3 | 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3  | xenial-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 libdbus-1-3 | 1.10.10-1ubuntu1   | yakkety          | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 libdbus-1-3 | 1.10.10-1ubuntu1.1 | yakkety-security | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 libdbus-1-3 | 1.10.10-1ubuntu1.1 | yakkety-updates  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 libdbus-1-3 | 1.10.10-1ubuntu1.2 | yakkety-proposed | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 libdbus-1-3 | 1.10.10-1ubuntu2   | zesty            | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
```

Comment: I will update to 16.04.2 beacuse the software i need do not allow older versions, ty for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
dpkg --force-all -i opera-stable_51.0.2830.55_amd64.deb
```

Parameter --force-all will install the Opera package despite the dependency problem. Good luck.

Comment: I normally wouldn't recommend anyone does a `--force-all`, but this "answer" allows Opera to be installed and open, which may be required for organizations stuck on Ubuntu 14.04.  https://i.imgur.com/zDD3Hj0.gifv